# View on New Activity Not Updating On UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

Sadly, this code is mostly too complicated to post all the interstices. However, I'll do my best to give the sparse amount of code which may contribute to the problem.

So I have some things running under the surface which are pushing out broadcasts whenever things get updated on the database (It's basically an interface to monitor a server (one that is not connected to the internet) on android.). I have broadcast receivers which are listening for these broadcasts and run a Runnable on the Handler whenever we get the broadcast we are looking for.

I'm using a fragment activity which is being called from main activity. This activity has a variable number of fragments which have a variable number of "widgets". These widgets have their own broadcast receivers, which are listening and responding as mentioned above. So, each broadcast is registered only when the view is created and unregistered upon its deletion, thus each broadcast receiver contains a reference to the item.

The problem is that using the same exact, working logic on my main activity does not work when I open up this second activity. For some reason, the view will not update when I request it to do so (such as textView.setText("blah") will display "blah" on the Main Activity, but display nothing on this new activity). Using print statements, I have noted that it thinks it is updated, so if I were to call "textView.setText("blah")" and then print "textView.getText()" it would print out "blah" despite note showing this on the UI.

This is the code I am using to call the task from within the BroadcastReceiver (Note that item is a weak reference to the item):

```
task = new MyRunnable();
if (item.get().getView() == null) return;
item.get().getView().post(task);
```

This is the code for one of the updating runnables (Where param is the intent from the broadcast and context is the application context and nameOfTextView is the name of the text view.):

```
String arg = param.getStringExtra(broadcast);
if (arg == null) return;

int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfTextView, 
    "id", context.getPackageName());
View view = item.get().getView();
if (id == 0 || view == null || !view.isShown()) return;

TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(id);
v.setText(arg);
```

I've been at this for hours with no luck. My best guess is that, for some reason or another, it's not referencing the correct widget. However, this doesn't seem likely as each broadcast is created by the widgets, meaning that the things that the reference it passes in should be valid.

Thank you in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**

After a great suggestion by @Mark Herscher, I have determined that my guess is incorrect. The view it is attempting to change is, in fact, the same view which is being displayed on the UI. I've checked, triple checked, found an issue and fixed an issue with threads running twice, and still the UI does not update correctly.

Again, this seems to not occur using the same broadcasts and runnables on the Main Activity. This problem is isolated to the other activities.

For those asking, here is the few lines of code which start the other activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GlobalSettingsActivity.class);
i.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, GLOBAL_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(i, GLOBAL_SETTINGS);
```

These activities extend a super type which utilizes the same code to be generated.

Comment: how do you create the second activity? Are you sure the `BroadcastReceiver` in the second Activity do actually receive the broadcasts?

Comment: Hello @JohnnyAW. Yes, I am sure they are receiving the broadcasts. Some change information about the item and that information is being changed correctly. The second activity is created through a standard `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: so you see the second activity and the initial values, but you can't change the values, right? Can you try to finish the first activity?

Comment: @JohnnyAW Sort of correct. Only the UI is not updating. The values associated with those displays ARE being updated. So, when I rotate the screen (or rather, destroy and recreate the view), the changes are visible, since it saves the data and then pulls from that (or shows some standard message/display if there is nothing there).

Comment: whats about finishing the first activity? What if you add a button and change the values on click?

Comment: @JohnnyAW I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: call `finish();` on the first activity right after `startActivityForResult()`. Add a button to your layout and try to update the values on click, just to see, that you are referencing the right views

Comment: @JohnnyAW I'm not sure that would work. The first activity is just on the stack. The uppermost activity I am discussing is a settings activity. The user will return to the main activity after viewing and/or making changes to the settings. Thus it would be undesirable to finish and then recreate this activity unless there was a memory issue. I'm also unsure of how this would interfere or cause the issue I am currently experiencing. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was thinking that you might have referenced Views from the first activity. If you finish the first activity and you still have the problems, then you can be sure there it has nothing to do with the first activity. Its just trial and error, try to isolate the source of the problem

Comment: @JohnnyAW As I mentioned before, I'm referencing the items, not the views. However, I tried finishing the activity as you suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: and your item is a fragment? Can you post an example of how you create the activity and your fragments?

Comment: It seems you're not even getting the correct View object. You can get the object using findViewById(), after inflate(). I am not clear on the object "item" and not likely to return the correct View object. Perhaps you should post more code for us to help.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid It is saving a reference to the view on create. These items are being created by the fragments which are placing these views as child views. @JohnnyAW, as I said before, I am literally just calling `startActivityForResult()` and the Fragments are being created by a PageViewer in the pretty standard "create a new fragment please" way.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you have started an AsyncTask in the second activity. Please make sure that your current activity does not have started a an AsyncTask. If an AsyncTask is executing in the background, please comment it and test the app again. Let me know your results.

Comment: No Async tasks are running. I haven't even made any.

Comment: The basic requirement for view.post(Runnable r) is that the view should be attached to the window for Runnable to be executed.      View.post() : Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread. This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window. However, I think both handler.post() and activity.runOnUIThread() are good to go. Try them too...

Comment: @RoseR When you check it please let us know.

Comment: we are all curious to know your results and findings, that's why I am disturbing you. Sorry if felt disgusting.

Comment: Hello, I'm not quite sure what you are saying? As my code clearly shows, I am using view.post() and posting a runnable? Though I have changed it to simply be new Handler.post(). This has not resolved the issue.

Comment: then, check whether do you have another text view with same id in your project? and please ensure that you cant update the text view even if you have only added one such view in the window

Comment: Sorry we are all curious to hear your results and findings:-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it sounds like you're holding a reference to an old view and updating that instead.

To test this, in your Activity's onCreate() set the tag* of all the relevant views to a random number. It takes an Object but you can get an int and then convert it to Integer. You can then retrieve the tag values while debugging and print their values. This should help tell you if you're actually updating the same instance or if you have multiple undesired instances.

Of course, this won't help you fix *how* that happened, and without more code it's difficult to say.

- (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll try this out immediately and let you know how it goes.

Comment: After some thorough testing, I have determined that the view is, in fact, the same view that is being displayed (tagging it and saving the tag before it is added to the view hierarchy, printing when it does this so I can determine if it is doing this multiple times, etc.).

Comment: Well that's almost disappointing. :) I'm at a loss at this time. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Since the problem "shouldn't be happening", here's what I would do: copy the entire project and start removing things from it until the problem goes away. Simplify logic, remove all GUI code that doesn't matter, and get it down to the bare minimum that still demonstrates the problem without any extra portions. Then hopefully you can either post this simplified code here, or you'll make a change and the problem will be gone, and then you'll know where to look.

Comment: Sadly, this project is thousands of lines of code, possibly tens of thousands. That is simply, and unfortunately, not a possibility during the short work time-frame.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the code `if (arg == null)` return, but the String parameter may be empty. For debugging suggestion, do `Log.d(TAG, "param= " + arg);` after that if block. If you want to see if there are concurrency issues you may do code like arg = arg + (increment number).  And then code Log.d.

Your post is not too clear on the problem, I suggest stating the problem again somewhere on the bottom of your post.

Comment: Yes, but I am reaching a print statement at the end of the code and it correctly prints the right text. As I mentioned in my problem statement, I have asked the view for the text back and gotten the correct text.